# ffmpeg convert cdg/mp3 to mp4 but cdg track is always sped up by a second

Tags: ffmpeg

I've tried this:

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg" -i %1 -i %2 -b:v 1M -y -speed 2 "%~dpn1.mp4"

"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg" -i %1 -i %2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -async 1 -speed 2 "%~dpn1.mp4"
```

Always same result. The file and quality are great, but obv since its karaoke... the lyrics need to match the timing and the converted files lyrics track is always about a full second or so ahead from when I play the original in a Karaoke program. Any ideas on what settings I could play with to help with this?

Both the original and the converted have the same play length at the end though. so the mp3 track seems to be ok.

**EDIT:**  Added cmd output

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg" -i "A:\25 Karaoke\English\Linkin Park - In The End [SF Karaoke].cdg" -i "A:\25 Karaoke\English\Linkin Park - In The End [SF Karaoke].mp3" -b:v 1M -y -speed 2 "LP_inTheEnd.mp4"
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, cdg, from 'A:\25 Karaoke\English\Linkin Park - In The End [SF Karaoke].cdg':
  Duration: 00:03:56.21, start: 0.480000, bitrate: 57 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: cdgraphics, pal8, 300x216, 300 fps, 300 tbr, 300 tbn, 300 tbc
[mp3 @ 000001bb3c14bb40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'A:\25 Karaoke\English\Linkin Park - In The End [SF Karaoke].mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : In The End [SF Karaoke]
    artist          : Linkin Park
    comment         : http://www.otslabs.com/
  Duration: 00:03:56.26, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Codec AVOption speed () specified for output file #0 (LP_inTheEnd.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (cdgraphics (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.1, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] 264 - core 158 r2984 3759fcb - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=7 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'LP_inTheEnd.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p(progressive), 300x216, q=-1--1, 1000 kb/s, 300 fps, 19200 tbn, 300 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
More than 1000 frames duplicated
More than 10000 frames duplicated   2048kB time=00:00:42.16 bitrate= 397.9kbits/s dup=9625 drop=0 speed=11.5x
frame=59170 fps=3226 q=-1.0 Lsize=   11887kB time=00:03:56.26 bitrate= 412.2kbits/s dup=43525 drop=0 speed=12.9x
video:7749kB audio:3340kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 7.203599%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] frame I:242   Avg QP: 0.26  size: 17214
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] frame P:16651 Avg QP: 0.14  size:   164
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] frame B:42277 Avg QP: 0.25  size:    25
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] consecutive B-frames:  2.7%  4.9%  3.8% 88.6%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] mb I  I16..4: 73.7%  1.6% 24.7%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.1%  P16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.4%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.7%  L0:44.2% L1:55.6% BI: 0.2%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] final ratefactor: -19.48
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] 8x8 transform intra:1.5% inter:14.0%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] coded y,u,v intra: 14.1% 14.8% 14.9% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 90%  0%  9%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 14% 63%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  1%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 55% 15% 16%  1%  2%  3%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.2% UV:0.2%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] ref P L0: 97.9%  0.9%  1.0%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] ref B L0: 99.6%  0.4%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] ref B L1: 99.9%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 000001bb3c13bc00] kb/s:321.80
[aac @ 000001bb3c172e40] Qavg: 6813.878
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: there was no log when I was trying.. i was just dropping the two files onto the script. I'll make a for loop to do all songs if i get it working.. updated with the cli of running it manually for a specific file

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ffmpeg -itsoffset 1 -i "Linkin Park - In The End [SF Karaoke].cdg" -itsoffset 0 -i "Linkin Park - In The End [SF Karaoke].mp3" -b:v 1M -y -speed 2 "LP_inTheEnd.mp4"
```

that's your original command (though without the windows-specific bits) adjusted with a timestamp offset of 1 on the video and zero on the audio, so that the video should delay one second but the audio should not.